# What is the correct way to export named components?

Tags: javascript

Is there a difference between exporting like this:

```
export const Foo ...
```

and this

```
const Foo ...
export { Foo }
```

Comment: I think one will export Foo and one will export an Object with Foo in it.  What do you imports look like?

Comment: In both cases, within the root `index.js` file, I can export them like this `export { Foo } from './Foo'`. So, it seems that they are interchangeable (?)

Answer (score 2):

There is not really a difference, with the second approach you could just export a list of names:

> After the `export` keyword, you can use `let`, `const`, and `var` declarations, as well as function or class declarations. You can also use the `export { name1, name2 }` syntax to export a list of names declared elsewhere. Note that `export {}` does not export an empty object — it's a no-op declaration that exports nothing (an empty name list). - [mdn web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export?retiredLocale=de)